# How to iterate this tree/graph

Tags: python, tree

I need to iterate a tree/graph and produce a certain output but following some rules:

```
     _ d
   /  / \
  b  c  _e
 /     / |
a     f  g
```

The expected output should be (order irrelevant):

```
{'bde', 'bcde', 'abde', 'abcde', 'bdfe', 'bdfge', 'abdfe', ...}
```

The rules are:

1. The top of the tree 'bde' (leftmost_root_children+root+rightmost_root_children) should always be present
2. The left-right order should be preserved so for example the combinations 'cb' or 'gf' are not allowed.
3. All paths follow the left to right direction.

I need to find all paths following these rules. Unfortunately I don't have a CS background and my head is exploding. Any tip will be helpful.

EDIT: This structure represents my tree very closely:

```
class N():
    """Node"""
    def __init__(self, name, lefts, rights):
        self.name = name
        self.lefts = lefts
        self.rights = rights

tree = N('d', [N('b', [N('a', [], [])], []), N('c', [], [])], 
              [N('e', [N('f', [], []), N('g', [], [])], 
                      [])])
```

or may be more readable:

```
N('d', lefts =[N('b', lefts=[N('a', [], [])], rights=[]), N('c', [], [])], 
       rights=[N('e', lefts=[N('f', [], []), N('g', [], [])], rights=[])])
```

Comment: Show what you have tried!

Comment: to be honest I don't know how to start. I was thinking a double for loop but I feel somehow I need to do some recursion. I just can't put everything together.

Comment: there is no direct route between d and f/g or b and c. it's really hard to uncover the logic (why and when to jump from d to g then go to f and back to e) behind your expected outputs.

Comment: What format is the tree in to begin with?

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for not being clear, truth is I am trying to clarify it myself and you are already being helpful. Thanks! I am trying to build a sample OrderedDict representing the tree and will update the question as soon as I get it.

Comment: You said that it's a binary tree, but d appears to have 3 children?  Is the example a mistake, or is it not binary?

Comment: @BielaDiela The problem is everybody here expects clear questions for which one can give clear precise answer. As regards your question, nobody can understand what is exactly expected :( Unfortunately, StackOverflow is not designed for prolonged discussion, though the question may be interesting.

Comment: so its a dict `{'d':{'b':{'a':None},'c':None,'e':{'f':None,'g':None}}}`?

Comment: @JoranBeasley, kind of but the left-right order is important, so always 'b' comes before 'c' and a simple dict would lose the order.

Comment: @ovgolovin, I understand you point, sorry for not being clear.

Comment: I think @JoranBeasley's illustration is the way to go. Honestly, unless there's some overarching rule here that needs to be dynamic (locating the leftmost-etc-etc part, for example), this seems pretty much like an `itertools` challenge. ;)

Comment: I'm not sure your diagram is accurate, if it is indeed a tree. You are representing `b`, `c`, and `d` as all connected to one another -- a 3-cycle. Trees, by definition, cannot contain cycles.

Comment: @GregEdelston, Yes you are right, it is actually a tree but I wanted to represent that 'bc' and 'fg' can be part of a path because they belong to the same level in the node. If it is more clear with the lines removed I will take them away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this can be treated as a combination of two problems. My code below will assume the `N` class and `tree` structure have already been defined as in your problem statement.

**First:** given a tree structure like yours, how do you produce an in-order traversal of its nodes? This is a pretty straightforward problem, so I'll just show a simple recursive generator that solves it:

```
def inorder(node):
    if not isinstance(node, list):
        node = [node]
    for n in node:
        for left in inorder(getattr(n, 'lefts', [])):
            yield left
        yield n.name
        for right in inorder(getattr(n, 'rights', [])):
            yield right

print list(inorder(tree))
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'e']
```

**Second:** Now that we have the "correct" ordering of the nodes, we next need to figure out all possible combinations of these that **a)** maintain this order, and **b)** contain the three "anchor" elements (`'b', 'd', 'e'`). This we can accomplish using some help from the always-handy [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) library.

The basic steps are:

- Identify the anchor elements and partition the list into four pieces around them
- Figure out all combinations of elements for each partition (i.e. the power set)
- Take the product of all such combinations

Like so:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
# powerset recipe taken from itertools documentation
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def traversals(tree):
    left, mid, right = tree.lefts[0].name, tree.name, tree.rights[0].name
    nodes = list(inorder(tree))
    l_i, m_i, r_i = [nodes.index(x) for x in (left, mid, right)]
    parts = nodes[:l_i], nodes[l_i+1:m_i], nodes[m_i+1:r_i], nodes[r_i+1:]
    psets = [powerset(x) for x in parts]
    for p1, p2, p3, p4 in product(*psets):
        yield ''.join(chain(p1, left, p2, mid, p3, right, p4))

print list(traversals(tree))
# ['bde', 'bdfe', 'bdge', 'bdfge', 'bcde', 'bcdfe', 
#  'bcdge', 'bcdfge', 'abde', 'abdfe', 'abdge', 'abdfge', 
#  'abcde', 'abcdfe', 'abcdge', 'abcdfge']
```

Comment: Great answer! Now I know how far I was from being able to do it myself. Thanks!